# How can I create a yaml file from pure python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Example from [Using YAML with Python](http://mikkel.elmholdt.dk/?p=4)

Original YAML file contains this

```
# tree format
treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: Node 1
        branch1-1:
            name: Node 1-1
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
        branch2-1:
            name: Node 2-1
```

After loading the content from the file using `yaml.load()` , and dump it into a new YAML file, I get this instead:

```
# tree format
treeroot:
    branch1:
        branch1-1: {name:Node 1-1}
        name: Node 1
    branch2:
        branch2-1: {name: Node 2-1}
        name: Node 2
```

What is the proper way of building up a YAML file straight from pure python? I don't want to write string myself. I want to build the dictionary and list.

---

Partial...

```
dataMap = {'treeroot':
               {'branch2': 
                 {'branch1-1': 
                  {'name': 'Node 1-1'},   # should be its own level
                  'name': 'Node 1'
                 }
               }
          }
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can guarantee getting the same file out as in?  If so, there is no guarantee, because dictionaries have no predefined order.

Comment: @Nate Right, that's my intention. I understand that. I edited and provided part of the structure. Yaml dumps can't parase the inner {name: Node 1-1} into another level....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OKay. I just double checked the documentation. We need this at the end of the `yaml.dump(data, optional_args)`

The fix is this

```
yaml.dump(dataMap, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

where dataMap is the source `yaml.load()` and f is the file to be written to.

Comment: This dump doesn't write the `#tree format` comment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using PyYAML as you probably are, the output you show is **not** copy-paste of what a `yaml.dump()` generated as it includes a comment, and PyYAML doesn't write those.

If you want to preserve that comment, as well as e.g the key ordering in the file (nice when you store the file in a revision control system) use ¹:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
# tree format
treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: Node 1
        branch1-1:
            name: Node 1-1   # should be its own level
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
        branch2-1:
            name: Node 2-1
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
print yaml.dump(data, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper, indent=4)
```

which gets you **exactly** the input:

```
# tree format
treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: Node 1
        branch1-1:
            name: Node 1-1   # should be its own level
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
        branch2-1:
            name: Node 2-1
```

¹ <sub>This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) an enhanced version of PyYAML of which I am the author.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your first and second listings are equivalent, just different notation.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Associative_arrays and http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Dictionarieswithoutnestedcollectionsarenotdumpedcorrectly