# Python3: Parsed Xlsx to dictionary and produced a yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

PTPA

Not sure if this is allowed if not please delete it

I am a novice in python and was trying to create a script that will parse xlsx data to python and use it to create a yaml file that will be used for ansible purpose.

Im stuck with the following type of excel column:

|    Column A   |

|:—————:|

| CA.1    | CA.2  |

|:—————:|:—————:|

| VA.1          | VA.2  |

I wanted to put it in a dictionary like for example:

Column A: { ColumnA.1 : ValueA.1 , ColumnA.2 : Value A.2}

So that I could create a yaml file like:

Column A:

- ColumnA.1 : Value A.1
- ColumnA.2 : Value A.2

I would appreciate your input on this one. Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

At a high level I would:

- use pandas to ingest the Excel file `pd.read_excel` - [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)
- list comprehension to create the dictionary [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)
- and `yaml.dump` to generate your file [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135275/how-can-i-create-a-yaml-file-from-pure-python)

**edit:**

be sure to look at how `yaml.dump` executes, this will inform how you turn the pandas dataframe into a dictionary -- though you might be able to use `df.to_dict()`, depending on how your Excel file is structured ([to_dict docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html))